# Change Toolbar Title in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to use my custom text instead of App Name in toolbar
I use this in my `xml`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="my toolbar"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and use this

```
 Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView mytext=findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in MainActivity
but it show like this

**myapp**

[image]

how i can correct it to just display my text?

Comment: you have to hide default text of toolbar after that you can display your own text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `TextView` inside the `Toolbar`, you don't need that.

Add this line to the `Toolbar` definition

```
app:title="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: Thank you .its work. should i use this for every Layout i create?

Comment: Yes, use it to every `Toolbar` you have

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView mytext=findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupprotActionBar().setTitle(" ");  // impotent
```

**UPDATE :**

or you can do it in manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".SelectionActivity"
    android:label="" <!-- impotent -->
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
```

`setDisplayShowTitleEnabled` will help you to  disable title from the Toolbar.